# PHP wordpress contact form

Tags: php, wordpress, forms

im trying to send the email and redirect it, here is my code so far.

```
<?php 
if (isset($_POST['formName'], $_POST['formEmail'], $_POST['formSubject'], $_POST['formMessage'])) {

$errors = array();

        $formName    = sanitize($_POST['formName']);
        $formEmail   = sanitize($_POST['formEmail']);
        $formSubject = sanitize($_POST['formSubject']);
        $formMessage = sanitize($_POST['formMessage']);

        $required_fields = array('formName', 'formEmail', 'formSubject', 'formMessage');
            foreach($_POST as $key=>$value){
                if(empty($value) && in_array($key, $_required_fields) === true){
                    $errors[] = 'Fields marked with an asterisk are required';
                    break 1;
                } 
              }

        if(empty($errors)){
            $to         = 'pwnd999@msn.com';
            $subject    = $formSubject; 
            $body       = $formMessage;
            $header     = 'From: ' . $formEmail;

             wp_mail($to, $suject, $body, $header);

             wp_redirect( get_permalink() . '?success' );
              exit;

              }  else {
                 $errors[] = 'Something when wrong!'; 
              }

function sanitize($data){
 $data = trim($data);
 $data = stripslashes($data);
 $data = htmlspecialchars($data);
return $data;
 }

}


   if (isset($_GET[ 'success'])==true) { ?>
<div class="messageSent pannel">
<h1>Message sent successfully!</h1>
<p>I will try to reply as fast as possible however, feel free to send me a    text message!</p>
</div>
<?php } else{ ?>

<form id="contactForm" method="POST" autocomplete="off" action="">
<?php if(!empty($errors)): ?>
<div class="errors pannel row">
    <div class="col-md-8">
        <ul>
            <h3><li><?php echo implode('</li><li>', $errors);?></li><h3>  </ul>
            </div>
            <div class="col-md-4">
                 <?php include(TEMPLATEPATH ."/panels/SVG/sadeFace.php"); ?>
            </div>
        </div>

    <?php endif; ?>

  <div class="form-group">
   <label for="name"><h3>Name <span class="star">*</span></h3></label>
            <span class="error"><?php echo $nameErr;?></span>
            <div class="inputWrap">
                <input type="text" required autocomplete="off" class="form-control" id="name" name="name" placeholder="Danny Devito" <?php echo isset($formName) ? 'value="' . $formName . '"' : '' ?>>
               <?php include(TEMPLATEPATH ."/panels/SVG/name.php"); ?>
            </div>
    </div>
    <div class="form-group">
        <label for="email">
            <h3>Email <span class="star">*</span></h3></label>
        <div class="inputWrap">
            <input type="email" required autocomplete="off" class="form-control" name="email" id="email" placeholder="devito@hollywood.com" <?php echo isset($formEmail) ? 'value="' . $formEmail . '"' : '' ?>>
         <?php include(TEMPLATEPATH ."/panels/SVG/email.php"); ?>
        </div>
    </div>
    <div class="form-group">
        <label for="subject">
            <h3>Subject <span class="star">*</span></h3></label>
        <div class="inputWrap">
            <input type="text" required autocomplete="off" class="form-control" name="subject" id="subject" placeholder="Design me a website!" <?php echo isset($formSubject) ? 'value="' . $formSubject . '"' : '' ?>>
           <?php include(TEMPLATEPATH ."/panels/SVG/idea.php"); ?>
        </div>
    </div>
    <div class="form-group">
        <label for="message">
            <h3>What can I help you with? <span class="star">*</span></h3></label>
        <div class="inputWrap">
            <textarea required autocomplete="off" name="message" class="form-control" id="message" placeholder="Hello Carl," value="poo">
                <?php echo isset($formMessage) ? $formMessage : '' ?>
            </textarea>
            <?php include(TEMPLATEPATH ."/panels/SVG/message.php"); ?>
        </div>
    </div>
    <button type="submit" name="submitted" class="btn main">Submit</button>
</form>
<?php }
 ?>
```

Comment: Questions seeking debugging help ("why isn't this code working?") must include the desired behavior, a specific problem or error and the shortest code necessary to reproduce it in the question itself. Questions without a clear problem statement are not useful to other readers.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This is caused by the name of your field Name (`name="name"`) that conflicts with the name parameter of WP_Query.

If you change that into `name="formName"` it should work.

Also you need to change the names of your other fields, not because of the previous reason, but because they don't match the names at the top of your code.

Comment: as an additional advice I invite you to use a [nonce](https://codex.wordpress.org/WordPress_Nonces) in your form for security reasons